# Can an unrefrenced objects be refrenced again?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

As subject says: Can an unrefrenced objects be refrenced again?

I came across this question at http://www.javatpoint.com/corejava-interview-questions-4 Q120. I tried Googling for this but did not find any link. How do we actually do it?

Comment: please type in the text of your question. You may include the link for reference too however just providing link is very wrong. What if tomorrow that link is dead? Your question will make no sense!

Comment: In answer to the question:  Generally, no.  There are probably special oddball cases one can come up with (or terminology things one can dance around), but, for all practical purposes, once all references to an object are gone then the object is no longer accessible.

Comment: The following article discusses several kinds of references and explains the resurrection problem: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below example is not a "in the wild" example, but it demonstrate how an unreferences object might be "resurrected" by the `finalize` method. This could happen only once. If the object of first instance becomes unreferenced a second time, the `finalize()` method will not be called again.

```
public class Resurrect {

    static Resurrect resurrect = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Resurrect localInstance = new Resurrect();
        System.out.println("first instance: " + localInstance.hashCode());

        // after this code there is no more reference to the first instance
        localInstance = new Resurrect();
        System.out.println("second instance: " + localInstance.hashCode());

        // will (in this simple example) request the execution of the finalize() method of the first instance
        System.gc(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void finalize() {
        resurrect = this;
        System.out.println("resurrected: " + resurrect.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an integer attribute to Resurrect class and tried to access it after garbage collection. Sometimes it is working fine, sometimes it is giving null pointer exception. So I think, it is not guaranteed that it will work everytime. If the object is removed from memory before accessing it, it will give null pointer exception.

Comment: @pkgajulapalli How do you access the `Resurrect` object and the `int` property? The line `resurrect = this` creates a reference to the object itself, therefore it is not garbage collected after the `finalize()` method is finished.

Comment: Take a look at this code. https://justpaste.it/1ejqt. Run it multiple times to see null pointer exception.

Comment: @pkgajulapalli Becuase you access `resurrect` before the `finalize` method was executed. And there is no guarantee when and if at all it will happen. Therefor `resurrect` is still null. If you amend your line to `System.out.println("After GC resurrected obj:" + resurrect);` you will see that the output from the `finalize()` comes after in such case.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks for the explanation.